# Opening nautilus from command line produces errors, doesn't return control to terminal

Tags: command-line, nautilus

When I run the command `nautilus &`, the file browser opens correctly, but prints the following errors and doesn't return control to the terminal (e.g. what the `&` should do):

```
(nautilus:6279): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:6279): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:6279): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(nautilus:6279): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nautilus:6279): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

What's going on?

EDIT: To clarify, the issue is that gedit doesn't get detatched when I use the `&`.

Comment: You can ignore these warnings. But remember to never run `sudo nautilus`!

Comment: Right @edwinksl, instead use `gksudo nautilus` for root access

Comment: For admim level stuff in nautilus there's a plugin for than, `nautilus-admin` , so that can be an alternative as well

Comment: @edwinksl, why not `sudo nautilus`, and use `gksudo nautilus` instead? Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema Because there's a serious risk of breaking userspace permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nautilus is running fine , there are some warnings but they are not a problem.

If you want it to detatch when you run it stick an & on the end

```
nautilus &
```

Comment: But that's the issue, when I stick an & at the end it doesn't detatch!

Comment: It probably has detached, hit enter and the prompt will appear

Comment: Oh. Fair enough

Comment: Use `nohup nautilus 2>&1 > /dev/null &` . This sends command line output to black hole and returns control to terminal

Comment: Nohup is a bad idea , it will try to keep it running after the terminal or xsession closes. Only use nohup for remote CLI not local GUI apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the following to your .bash_alias

```
alias nautilus='nautilus >/dev/null 2>&1'
```

so that all the output is no longer visible on the command line when you call nautilus.